# SQL- Adding a condition

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I am just starting to learn SQL.

How do you add a condition to a statement?  I am trying to sort the destination to 'BNA' which is the airport code.

```
 SELECT 
 CHARTER.CUS_CODE,
 CHARTER.DESTINATION "AIRPORT",
 CHARTER.CHAR_DATE, 
 CHARTER.CHAR_DISTANCE,
 CHARTER.AC_NUMBER,
 FROM C.CHARTER ;

 WHERE DESTINATION = 'BNA' ;
```

Any hints in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Huh?  Not clear on your question.  If you want sorted output, add an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Well if I just leave the code as "destination", the output would be all the destinations.  I just want to sort by one destination and leave out the rest.

Comment: When you sort something, your order it. When you leave something out, you filter it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help.  I want to filter it than.  The revised code wont compile successfully for me.

Comment: @Chris did you try the sql in my post? The table in the from clause should most likely be "CHARTER" not "C.HARTER" and you need to put the semicolon at the end of the query only. You have a semicolon after the from clause, which is not needed. The semicolon signals the end of a query.

Comment: @ShWiVeL, Yes I have used your code.  I get a compile error on line 7  "missing expression".

Comment: Are you sure all of the field names are correct and they are on the table called "CHARTER"? Also what type of database is this (Oracle, sql server, mysql, etc.)?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer.  All the table names are correct.  It is coming from a users tables.  I just didnt want to include the users name on here, so I left it out..thats what that c was.

Comment: There is an extra comma after charter.ac_number (sorry I must have glazed over it before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is your query with the syntax corrected:

```
SELECT CHARTER.CUS_CODE,
       CHARTER.DESTINATION "AIRPORT",
       CHARTER.CHAR_DATE,
       CHARTER.CHAR_DISTANCE,
       CHARTER.AC_NUMBER
  FROM CHARTER
 WHERE DESTINATION = 'BNA';
```

1. The semicolon goes at the end only.
2. Get rid of "c." from the table name in your from clause. You might have been thinking of giving it an alias of "c" which, if if that's the case, you would put it after the table name (and then use it as a prefix for each field).

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT 
 CHARTER.CUS_CODE,
 CHARTER.DESTINATION "AIRPORT",
 CHARTER.CHAR_DATE, 
 CHARTER.CHAR_DISTANCE,
 CHARTER.AC_NUMBER,
 FROM C.CHARTER 
 WHERE DESTINATION = 'BNA' ;
```

The `;` character is a statement terminator; you only need one per SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

there is ";" at the end of the FROM statement, remove it. and try the sql again. Pay attention with the double quote too on the AIRPORT text.

```
SELECT CHARTER.DESTINATION + 'AIRPORT ' 
 FROM C.CHARTER
 WHERE DESTINATION = 'BNA' ;
```

Comment: I think he is just giving that column an alias of "airport", in which case it's fine. He probably doesn't want to concatenate the word "airport" to every destination.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. I always use "AS" to create Alias.